# Proof verification: In finite abelian groups, any subgroup generated by an element of maximal order is a direct summand.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and suppose $x\in G$ has largest order. Then $\langle x\rangle$ is a direct summand of $G$.

This exercise is intended to give an alternative proof of the fundamental theorem. My proof is as follows.

Set $|x|=n$. Let $H\leq G$ be maximal with respect to the property that $H\cap\langle x\rangle=0$. Suppose $G\neq H\oplus\langle x\rangle$, then we show that $H$ cannot be maximal.

Take $g\in G-(H\oplus\langle x\rangle)$. Let $k$ be the order of the image of $g$ in the quotient group $G/(H\oplus\langle x\rangle)$ under the canonical projection, then $k\mid |g|$. But $|g|\mid|x|$ (this follows from the fact that, give any two elements $a,b$ in an abelian group $G$, $G$ has an element of order $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$), it follows that $k\mid n$.

Also we have $kg=h+lx$ for some $h\in H$ and $l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Multplying by $n/k$, we have

$$-(n/k)h=(nl/k)x=0,\;\text{ by}\; H\cap\langle x\rangle=0$$

hence $\;n\mid(nl/k)$, i.e., $k\mid l$.

Set $y=g-\frac lkx$, then $ky=h$. Clearly $y\notin H$. We claim that $(H+\langle y\rangle)\cap\langle x\rangle=0$, from it will show that $H$ is not maximal. Suppose $h'+ry=sx\neq0$ for some $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $h'\in H$. Now $rg\in H\oplus\langle x\rangle$, thus $k\mid r$. But $ry=h\in H$, hence $sx=h+h'\neq0$, contradicting the assumption that $H\cap\langle x\rangle=0$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Could you explain the reason why $k\mid n$?

Comment: Since $x$ has maximal order, $|g|$ divides $|x|=n$. (This follows from the fact that, give any two elements $a,b$ in an abelian group $G$, $G$ has an element of order $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.) Since $k$ is the order of some homomorphic image of $g$, $k$ divides $|g|$.

Comment: I think you should mention this fact or you should give it first as an lemma.

Comment: Could you explain the reason why $y\notin H$?

Comment: @mesel Edited. $y\notin H$ because $y\in H$ would imply $g=y+(l/k)x\in H\oplus\langle x\rangle$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: $rg\in G/(H\oplus <x>)$?

Comment: @mesel It was a typo, fixed now. :)

Comment: Your proof seems to be correct and fine with me.

Comment: @mesel Thanks for the patience.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Your attempt would be much clearer and easier to read if you'd use more spacing and double dollar signs to enclose some of your formulas as this makes them skip a line and be centered.